# Assert.AreEqual failed Error C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, assert

I am pretty new to all this, so any help would be appreciated.

I have created a download image from url method and i need to test it.
 i have tried filling in the test parameters but i am unsure of what i am meant to be putting in.

Could you please tell me whats meant to go where,

Thank You.
Aaron

```
[TestMethod()]
public void DownloadImageFromURLTest()
{
    string url = "http://www.omnimedicalsearch.com/conditions-diseases/images/skin-mole.jpg";
    Image expected = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\skin-mole.jpg");
    Image actual = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\skin-mole.jpg"); ;
    actual = CloudConnection.DownloadImageFromURL(url);
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
    Assert.Inconclusive("Verify the correctness of this test method.");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
  string url = "http://www.omnimedicalsearch.com/conditions-diseases/images/skin-mole.jpg";
  Image expected = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\skin-mole.jpg");
  Image actual = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\skin-mole.jpg"); ;
  actual = CloudConnection.DownloadImageFromURL(url);

  MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
  expected.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
  String expectedBitmap = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
  ms.Position = 0;
  actual.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
  String actualBitmap = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());

  Assert.AreEqual(expectedBitmap, actualBitmap);
```

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't particularly expect `Image` to override `Equals` - there are loads of different ways in which you might want equality. It would make more sense to compare the data in the two streams (the file and the web version).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that `Assert.Equal(Image, Image)` will compare the contents of the two images instead it will be comparing the references. You should write a method that manually compare the two images

You can convert the images to Bitmap and then compare the bitmaps

Take a look at [Comparing Two Images in C#](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/domgreen/archive/2009/09/06/comparing-two-images-in-c.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

`expected` and `actual` are references to different objects.

`Assert.AreEqual` will only be able to compare the two images as references, as `Image` doesn't override `Equals` - there is no facility to check that the images have identical content. You will need to write this yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, As i said im still very new to this, How would i go about making this work?

Comment: @user1081326 - There are no test methods that will do that for you. You need to compare the images byte by byte, or pixel by pixel (though first comparing the dimensions could be a good optimization).

Comment: @AzharKhorasany - You mean your answer?